# How to implement UniqueCount in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to implement uniqueCount in spark scala

Below is the transformation i am trying to implement :

`case  when ([last_revision]=1) and ([source]=""AR"") then UniqueCount([review_uuid]) OVER ([encounter_id]) end`

> Input

```
|last_revision|source|review_uuid   |encounter_id|
|-------------|------|--------------|------------|
|1            |AR    |123-1234-12345|7654        |
|1            |AR    |123-7890-45678|7654        |
|1            |MR    |789-1234-12345|7654        |
```

> Expected Output

```
|last_revision|source|review_uuid   |encounter_id|reviews_per_encounter|
|-------------|------|--------------|------------|---------------------|
|1            |AR    |123-1234-12345|7654        |2                    |
|1            |AR    |123-7890-45678|7654        |2                    |
|1            |MR    |789-1234-12345|7654        |null                 |
```

> My code :

```
.withColumn("reviews_per_encounter", when(col("last_revision") === "1" && col("source") === "AR", size(collect_set(col("review_uuid")).over(Window.partitionBy(col("encounter_id"))))))
```

> My Output :

```
|last_revision|source|review_uuid   |encounter_id|reviews_per_encounter|
|-------------|------|--------------|------------|---------------------|
|1            |AR    |123-1234-12345|7654        |3                    |
|1            |AR    |123-7890-45678|7654        |3                    |
|1            |MR    |789-1234-12345|7654        |null                 |
```

> Schema :

```
last_revision : integer
source : string
review_uuid : string
encounter_id : string
reviews_per_encounter : integer
```

In place of 2(expected) i am getting value 3, not sure what mistake i am doing here.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: You're still doing a count distinct over all 3 rows, you're only showing it when it matches the condition. Best to create a dummy column where you set `uuid` to null for the rows you don't want to count. Then you can do a `count_distinct` over that https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#count_distinct-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-org.apache.spark.sql.Column...-

Comment: @ScootCork That's not the problem, using count_distinct results in the same output, since there are actually 3 unique "review_uuid" s in the dataframe. The problem is issued because we want to count distinct review_uuid's that are in rows which satisfy both predicates for `source` and `last_revision`.

Answer (score 0):

The output makes perfect sense, as I commented, this is because this:

```scala
size(collect_set(col("review_uuid")))
```

Means:

> give me the count of unique `review_uuid`s in the whole dataframe (result: 3)

What you're looking for is:

> give me the count of unique `review_uuid`s only if the source in the corresponding row is equal to "AR" and "last_revision" is 1 (result: 2)

Notice the difference, now this doesn't need `window functions` and `over` actually. You can achieve this both using subqueries or self joining, here's how you can do it using self left join:

```scala
df.join(
    df.where(col("last_revision") === lit(1) && col("source") === "AR")
      .select(count_distinct(col("review_uuid")) as "reviews_per_encounter"),
    col("last_revision") === lit(1) && col("source") === "AR",
    "left"
  )
```

Output:

```
+-------------+------+-----------+------------+---------------------+
|last_revision|source|review_uuid|encounter_id|reviews_per_encounter|
+-------------+------+-----------+------------+---------------------+
|            1|    AR|      12345|        7654|                    2|
|            1|    AR|      45678|        7654|                    2|
|            1|    MR|      78945|        7654|                 null|
+-------------+------+-----------+------------+---------------------+
```

(I used some random uuid's, they were too long to copy :) )